# Enable content type selection on Add List item

Tags: 2010, content-type

I have created a list that has multiple content types associated with it.  It seems that the Content Type dropdown is only visible when editing a list item.

I would like the users to be able to select the content type when they add a new list item rather than always having to take the default then having to edit the list item to change content types.

Is there a way to allow selection of the Content Type when adding items for specific lists ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to select a content type when creating a new item. See below:[image]

Comment: Thanks for you answer.  The default view when entering the list is the Browse tab so the method people use to add a new lost item is to the click the green "Add new item" link,  So no way to get the Content Type dropdown on the list details screen during add ?  Guess it's a user training issue ?

Comment: Ok. You can create links to individual content type forms like this:<a href="http://yoursite/Lists/listname/NewForm.aspx?ContentTypeId=0x01002CF74A4DAE39480396EEA7A4BA2BE5FB009CBCDDE56A142247B896B1DE93CE3843&RootFolder=%2FReusableContent&IsDlg=1">Add item using content type 1</a> . Just update the href attribute according to your environment. To get the href simply launch newform.aspx for each content type by selecting the content type from new item menu and right click on the form and view properties to get the href url